# Random line from a file.txt

Tags: java

Any tips why my random doesn't work? All i get in input are stacked lines from first to 11. I think it will be a small mistake but i can't figure it out :/

```
package pl.mtgpackgenerator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(59);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Common.txt");
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = reader2.readLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
          line = reader2.readLine();
          System.out.println(line);
        }
    reader2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `randomInt` ?

Comment: what you are trying achieve?

Comment: And your loop is only reading the first 11 lines!

Comment: Im trying to receive random eleven lines where in each line is text.

Comment: with "receive random eleven lines" you mean read 11 lines starting from a random line in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks for me as you are explicitly reading first 10 lines from the file, and you don't use your random.

You may, for example, read all lines to an `ArrayList` of `Strings`, one by one, and then use your `randomInt` to print a line at the `randomInt` number. Just use it like `arraylist.get(randomInt)`; if you named your list `arraylist`.

Comment: Thank you sir, ArrayList was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use randomInt to check the line number and only print that line, if exists (example below). In the above code, randomInt is not used anywhere.

```
int index = 0;
while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
    if(index++ == randomInt){
        System.out.println(line);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@gliacomo said if you refers the code do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(59);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Common.txt");
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(fr);
    for (int i = randomInt; i <= randomInt + 10; i++) {
        String line = reader2.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.8 you can do like this

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
...
Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(59);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("Common.txt"))
String resultString = lines.get(randomInt);
```